# CI class Pagination links trouble

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

This is the code i currently have.
P.S. I am currently editing this, trying to solve this problem whilst waiting for someone to solve it here. Im not quite sure why this is happening.

Pagination:

```
$character = $this->uri->segment(3);    
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/Controller/function/'.$character;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Model->browse_total_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if(!is_numeric($character)){$data['records'] = $this->Model->get_records_filtered($character,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));}
        else{ $data['records'] = $this->Model->get_records($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));}
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('browse', $data);
```

Whenever i go to my browse page, instead of being on the page 1 of my page on pagination. it is defaulted that im on page 2. Why? because i see this as my link.

> 1 **2** 3 >

Plus, i can't click on link 2 but i can on link 1. I don't know if this is how pagination_links works. but i find it odd. Anyways, im not sure if its related to my other problem.

The character part is for the letter chosen, so for example i only want to view results with A as their first letter the url should be.

```
index.php/controller/function/A/
```

So the per page of the pagination will be placed on the 4th segment. It has no error that way. But when i don't click on any letter and just show all results.

Whenever i click on a link(per page). The url looks like this.

```
index.php/controller/function/2/
```

but when i click on the next page, it goes as

```
 index.php/controller/function/2/4
```

so basically breaks the pagination and retrieves no result.

I have tried other solutions like adding IF/else statement that if character is null or not equal to `range('A','Z')` then the `$config['base_url']` should have no `.$character` on the end and the uri_segment should be on 3rd. But it still goes the same as above.

EDIT:

The 2nd problem was solved, i used something like this.

```
$character = $this->uri->segment(3);
$Alphabet = range('A','Z');
$flag = 0;

for($i=0;$i<26;$i++)
{
    if($character==$Alphabet[$i])
    {
        $flag +=1;
    }
}
```

Seems like, `if($character==range('A','Z'))` doesnt work as only now noticed when i echoed that range returns results of array so i had to loop. is there any better way to check than what ive done above?

Comment: Your page segment should be 3, not 4. index.php doesn't count as a segment. I'm guessing whatever you have in the real segment 4 currently is being cast as 2, thus defaulting to page 2.

Comment: So i should put index.php on my base_url on my config file?

coz if i dont put index.php. it will error as ci needs to go through index.php before your controller

Comment: I edited, my pagination. The 4 part is where a user selects a letter so the per page should be on 4 whilst the letter on 3. so thats why i made another model named get_records_filtered. 

I made 2 pagination on my controller as of now, from the last part of my question i added a loop that checks if the user has chosen a letter if not then it goes to the default pagination with page segment at 3.

whilst if a user clicks on a letter since the link on my view is this. foreach(range('A', 'Z')as $key=>$letter)
   {
  echo anchor('Controller/_browse/'.$letter, ' '.$letter);
   }

Comment: should look like this.

With letter clicked : controller/function/A/[perpage here]

without letter clicked: controller/function/[perpage here]

Comment: If you're using index.php in the urls (haven't setup url rewrite), you should set `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` in config.php. Then base_url() and other url helpers will automatically add it. I think I understand what you want with the pagination now and will post an answer.

Comment: Ahh i see, ill check on my config file

Comment: It doesnt add index.php on the pagination link. I now remember why i put index.php on my base_url in my config or in the base_url itself in the pagination config

Comment: I'll have a retreat, ill be back tomorrow. ill accept your answer by then.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. base_url() doesn't include the index page, but site_url() does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your pagination config, you have the pagination segment set to 4 regardless of the whether a letter is specified or not. But it should be 3 when there is no character if I'm understanding correctly.

Try something like this:

```
if(!is_numeric($character)) {
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $data['records'] = $this->Model->get_records_filtered($character,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
} else {
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $data['records'] = $this->Model->get_records($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
}
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

For checking for a character in the range, you can use

```
if (in_array(strtoupper($character), range('A', 'Z'))
```

The strtoupper() is optional. Leave it in if you want 'a' to match 'A'.

Comment: Would i still need to insert index.php in my config['base_url']?

Comment: btw what is num_links for? i dont quite understand the explanation of ellislab, they didnt elaborate much

Comment: So long as your urls need to include 'index.php' in them, then yes. As I mentioned in the question comments, site_url() will automatically add it. num_links sets the number of numbered links in the generated pagination links. For example: num_links = 1 outputs < 1 **2** 3 >, num_links = 3 outputs < 1 2 3 **4** 5 6 7 >

Comment: So it sets the default page? Like how you bolded the 2 part where num_links is 1. or am i misunderstanding?

anyways, the line of code you add of If(in_array).. only works or should only run, assuming $character is not null, correct?

Comment: No, sorry. It sets the number of links that come before and after the current page. The bold number is the current page. So for the second example, 4 is the current page, and with num_links set to 3, it adds the last 3 numbers before the 4 and the next 3 numbers after the 4.

Comment: The if statement with in_array should only return true if $character is a single alphabetic character (a-z or A-Z). Numbers, null, strings longer than 1 character, etc should return false.

Comment: Ah okay, i thought i wouldv needed to check if the variable was null or not. else it would return php error saying undefined variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48693/discussion-between-user3205047-and-samutz)

Comment: btw, i am still stuck on that default page 2. instead of 1. :(

Comment: Rejoin the chat and I'll try to help.